# Getting data from couchbase bucket with a variable

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway, sql++

there is something I wonder: In my map reduce function, can I take "parent" property as a variable ? Like that :

```
function (doc, meta) {

  var key,value;
    if(doc.type == "mainForums" && doc.parent == **VAR**){
   key = [doc.type,doc.id]
   value = {Id : doc.id, Title : doc.title, Description : doc.description, Parent: doc.parent, HasChild : doc.hasChild, Level : doc.level, ImageUrl : "http://icon.donanimhaber.com/mobile-forum-icons/" + doc.iconPath, AvarageColor: doc.avarageColor,  RepMode : doc.repMode, iconPath : doc.iconPath, MessageCountThisWeek : doc.messageCountThisWeek, TopicCountThisWeek : doc.topicCountThisWeek}

  emit(key, value);
  }
}
```

Since I'm creating map reduce function on the couchbase console, I don't get how can I add a variable to this function. I'm doing the mapping part on MVC, as below:

```
var tempForum = new Forum
                {
                    Id = item.Id,
                    Title = item.Title,
                    Description = item.Description,
                    HasChild = item.HasChild,
                    Level = item.Level,
                    iconPath = item.iconPath,
                    Parent = item.Parent,
                    IsFavorite = item.IsFavorite,
                    TopicCountThisWeek = item.TopicCountThisWeek,
                    MessageCountThisWeek = item.MessageCountThisWeek,
                    RepMode = item.RepMode,
                    ForumExtra = item.ForumExtra
}
```

to print the json on the screen properly. I should take what mobile(android) programmer gives me as a variable, lets say 4, and bring him parent=4 docs from the sync_gateway. Or should android programmer do that map reduce thing?

Maybe I should forget about views and use only N1QL on a situation like that? Because I'm able to do it with N1QL but i  want to do it with views too, because I may need views later. I'm not really sure what is the best and I'm really confused.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Really? No one? Maybe @SimonBaslé can help me with this, no? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is a good use case for views, which can't be parameterized and are not really build to return a full hierarchy of documents.

The `value` you `emit` is what gets stored in the index (and passed to the `reduce` function), so it's **really** redundant to store full contents, generally not a good idea.
The configurable number of parents bit is even further from what views can support AFAIK.

So I'd advise to stick with N1QL, or maybe find a way to do that half on the server (N1QL), half on the client?